# Domain-wide cookies not saving in Chrome for .uk Second Level Domain

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, cookies, session-cookies

Google Chrome doesn't seem to be saving my domain-wide session cookie.

My server is sending the following headers out:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 26 Jun 2014 19:42:48 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: AuthID=a0dbc62667968c7d3c47dd80068a8b76; path=/; domain=.aerox.uk
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 109
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=50
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

But on subsequent requests the cookie is not being sent back out. If I try the same page in Internet Explorer is works just fine. Also if I change it from a domain-wide cookie to a sub-domain specific one it also works fine.

If I click on the page icon in the address bar and look at cookies set by this domain it shows none in either the allowed or blocked lists.

---

Here is some of my cookie config.

In `.htaccess`:

```
# PHP Settings
php_value session.cookie_domain ".aerox.uk"
php_value session.name "AuthID"
#php_flag session.auto_start 1

php_value auto_prepend_file "../auto_header.php"
```

In `auto_header.php`:

```
<?php
session_name('AuthID');
session_set_cookie_params(0,'/','.aerox.uk');
session_start();
?>
```

Comment: I've tried this in Google Chrome Cancary (38.0.2076.0) and it works as expected. I've also tried this on Google Chrome for Android (35.0.1916.141) where it doesn't work and the release edition for PC which didn't work was (35.0.1916.153).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing a few different versions and releases of Google Chrome it seems to be an issue with how releases prior to 36 treat .uk Second Level Domains (SLD).

I've searched through the change logs and found that versions prior to version 36 use an old version of the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/).

[This is the change that fixes Chrome to allow .uk domains to work correctly](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/37c3ef80c41dac21b35affd5055f83ddfca2b8ee)